# Gedmo Timestampable and Blameable doesnt work after Merge Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities. Schemas like this:

```
 /*
 * @ORM\MappedSuperClass
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */

abstract class BaseEntity {

/**
 * @var string $createdBy
 *
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_by", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $createdBy;

/**
 * @var \DateTime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $createdAt;
```

Other entity like this:

```
 /**
  * Survey
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="answers")
       *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\SomeBundle\Repository\Answer\AnswerRepository")
  */
 class Answer extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

---

Question is:

```
    $data = $em->merge($datas);
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();
```

After this process **Gedmo Blameable, Timestampable doesn't work.**

What should I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: I'd suggest filling and issue on github - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: thanks Thomas. Its a known issues thats what github issue says.  https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1399#issuecomment-136180088

Comment: Did you find your answer there?

Comment: Yes. Its a known issue. Its limitation of Gedmo Bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue. Its means limitation of Gedmo Bundle (Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions). I have to set all values (Blameable, Timestampable, Sortable etc..) manually.

Comment: This seems like a to much work for a simple code. I'm thinking of rather not using merge, if possible. What do you need it for? Could you show the code before the merge?

Comment: Yes Thomas its is :) . Yes its posibile and I deleted all codes and manually set all those values. I have very long json and i have 7 related entities. Its for json parsing and parsed values to write to db.